# Finding biggest square sub matrix has values 1 in a Matrix which has values 1 and 0

Tags: algorithm

i have axb matrix has values 1 or 0, I need to find the largest square sub matrix includes only ones. And i need to understdand how to do it. i mean i neeed algorthim. Example:

```
Matrix is 5x5 [ 1 1 1 1 1
                1 1 1 0 0
                1 1 1 0 0
                1 0 1 1 1
                1 1 1 1 1 ]     largest is 3x3 , starting position 0,0 and return value 3
```

another example:

```
Matrix is 5x5 [ 0 1 1 1 1
                0 1 1 1 1
                1 1 1 1 1
                1 1 1 1 1
                1 0 1 0 1 ] 

largest is 4x4 , starting position 0,1 and return value 4
```

Since program will be done multiple programing languages i need an algorithm. But you can basicly write a code for "C" to explain...

Comment: What time complexity are you aiming for? (assume metrix size is n x n)

Comment: i need a simple idea

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if this is the optimal solution but it is a simple idea.

Take you 5x5 matrix and create from it a 4x4 matrix in the following way:

Each 2x2 matrix it turning to a 1x1 matrix which is 1 if all of the original numbers where 1 and else - 0.

```
Matrix is 5x5 [ 1 1 1 1 1
                1 1 1 0 0
                1 1 1 0 0
                1 0 1 1 1
                1 1 1 1 1 ]
```

Will turn to

```
Matrix is 4x4 [ 1 1 0 0
                1 1 0 0
                0 0 0 0
                0 0 1 1 ]
```

Now we repeat the process:

```
Matrix is 3x3 [ 1 0 0
                0 0 0
                0 0 0 ]
```

And again:

```
Matrix is 2x2 [ 0 0
                0 0 ]
```

Now this is all zeros, we can search for the smallest matrix that still contains 1's. This can tell us where the original 1's matrix was and the size of the matrix relatively to the size of the original matrix can tell us how large it was. In our case it's top left in 3x3 so originally it was a 3x3 matrix at the top left.

The action we are performing is actually a convolution with 2x2 matrix of 1's and than rounding down. A Lot of programing languages have a library with this functionality.

The time complexity for a single convolution is `O(n^2)`, but we are performing this `n` times so the time complexity is `O(n^3)`.

Another example:

```
Matrix is 5x5 [ 0 1 1 1 1
                0 1 1 1 1
                1 1 1 1 1
                1 1 1 1 1
                1 0 1 0 1 ] 

Matrix is 4x4 [ 0 1 1 1
                0 1 1 1
                1 1 1 1
                0 0 0 0 ] 

Matrix is 3x3 [ 0 1 1
                0 1 1
                0 0 0 ] 

Matrix is 2x2 [ 0 1
                0 0 ]

Matrix is 1x1 [ 0 ]
```

So the top right in the 2x2 is the last left which mean the original was top right 4x4.

Comment: Although intriguing, this will only work for quadratic sub matrices, not for e.g. a 5x2 sub matrix of 1s.

Comment: "I need to find the largest **square** sub matrix" @Ridcully

Comment: Sorry, I overlooked that

Comment: It's ok, I did as well then I started to write a second answer and only then noticed that myself @Ridcully haha